# Yet another "no route matches" question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Man there are a lot of these questions but so far I have not found my particular problem.

I have this custom route showing when I run rake routes (this is not how I plan to have it long term just to test the routing out).

```
# routes.rb
match 'books/:id/file/:name' => 'home#download', :as => :download_book, :via => :get

# rake routes
download_book GET    /book/:id/file/:name(.:format)              {:controller=>"books", :action=>"download"}
```

In the view I have

```
= link_to name, download_book_path(@book.id, name: name)
```

And of course my `HomeController`, which is already serving another simple custom route so I know it's working, has a `download` action defined.

So the million dollar question is what is up with this error?

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:controller=>"home", :action=>"download", :name=>"test.zip", :id=>"fcd5c87aef84874eec8f08cc313da85c"}):
    14: %p
    15:   %b Published:
    16:   - @book.attachments.keys.each do |name|
    17:     = link_to name, download_book_path(@book.id, name: name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the dot in your `name` variable, which doesn't work out of the box in routes as it conflicts with the standard `(.:format)` route section, as you see in your `rake routes` call.

The solution can be found in [the rails guide on routing.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) To quote:

> By default dynamic segments don’t accept dots – this is because the dot is used as a separator for formatted routes. If you need to use a dot within a dynamic segment add a constraint which overrides this – for example :id => /[^/]+/ allows anything except a slash.

So if you do like they say here and change the constraint to allow dots, it should work:

```
match ..., :constraints => { :name => /[^\/]+/ }
```

---

Side note, in your example you're passing `name` in a hash, which would be interpreted as query string variables.

```
# Rather it should simply be
= link_to name, download_book_path(@book.id, name)
```

Comment: Sorry that was me trying to be explicit, the problem is the same either way I do it.

Comment: That isn't it either.  I've added `:format => false` to the route and it has no effect.  Besides that shouldn't cause it to not find the route when loading a view with a link should it?

Comment: Wow, WTH, that is it actually, color me shocked and confused.  Why th hell can't I get the URL format I want.  I am looking for a /{filename} here, this should be able to work.  They way you've shown above produces this `/books/{id}/file/{name}?={extention}` which is still not quite right.

Comment: Ok so I found this [link](http://zargony.com/2009/05/05/routing-parameters-with-a-dot) which explains this problem, but I'm still shocked.  If this is what is required to simply have a dot in a route, that is just terrible.  Please tell me there is a better way here.